# Visual Studio Code 2022 Community: get and enable all windows elements (controls) from toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, toolbox

I am using Visual Studio Code 2022 Community IDE. When I am working on a web form designer and opening the toolbox not all windows forms elements (controls) are available. I do right-click on toolbox - show all and when I click on all windows forms dropdown list all elements from list "all windows forms" are blocked and I can't drag none of those to web form designer.

I also do right-click on toolbox - choose items - reset all configuration and I've got same problem. And go start - visual studio 2022 - visual studio installer and clicking by repair option and there is no solution.

How can I do to get all windows forms elements (controls) available and enabled and unlocked to drag any control to web form designer?

Comment: The development configuration from my visual studio 2022 community ide is "General". Should I use "C#" like development configuration?